# Highlighted text in Eclipse unreadable

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

After upgrading to Ubuntu MATE 18.04 and Eclipse Oxygen, I find that highlighted text is hardly legible (shown in line 138):

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be an issue with the OS color scheme. However, the following works for me:

- In the menu, go to **Window > Preferences**.
- Go to **General > Editors > Text Editors**.
- Select **Selection background color** in the list. Uncheck **System Default** and click the color button. Set it to your preferred highlight color (for the Ambiance-MATE theme, that is `#86A551`).

Result:

[image]